# PHP cURL is not working on Cpanel (Linux) Server (ehost.com)

Tags: php, linux, curl

i am facing problem regarding **PHP cURL**. Actually i am sending HTTP Header through PHP cURL Command. It is working fine on Localhost(Xampp) but when i upload the Same code on Hosting Server(ehost.com) then it is not working. Also i have already check on Hosting Server that cURL is enable there. i have check through `<?php phpinfo() ?>` and it is showing that cURL is ENABLE.

below is my Code:

```
<?php

$uri = 'http://localhost/kafapp/api/transactions';
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER  => array('Authorization: 01501fe892e556fcd7cf841bd0ce9999'),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  =>true,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE     => 1
));
$out = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $out;

?>
```

Any Idea or Suggestion will be Appreciated.